# What is (setq comment-style 'aligned) supposed to do?

Tags: comment

First let me show a few things that work correctly. I am doing everything shown below using `emacs -q foo.txt` in a text buffer.

I make these settings first:

```lisp
(setq comment-start "<<")
(setq comment-end ">>")
(setq comment-style 'box)
(setq comment-column 25)
```

I have this text buffer:

```
The quick brown fox
jumps over
the lazy dog
```

If I select the three lines with `C-SPC C-n C-n C-n` and press `M-;`. The buffer becomes like this:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>
<< The quick brown fox >>
<< jumps over          >>
<< the lazy dog        >>
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>
```

All good. This is what I expected. Now I undo the change and revert the text to original state.

But now I change the comment style to:

```
(setq comment-style 'aligned)
```

Then I select the three lines of text again and press `M-;`. I get this:

```
<< The quick brown fox >>
<< jumps over >>
<< the lazy dog >>
```

The comment ends are not aligned. I was expecting this:

```
<< The quick brown fox >>
<< jumps over          >>
<< the lazy dog        >>
```

Is `comment-style` `'aligned` supposed to align the comment ends or not? If not what is `'aligned` supposed to do?

---

The value of `comment-styles` on my Emacs:

```
((plain nil nil nil nil "Start in column 0 (do not indent), as in Emacs-20")
 (indent-or-triple nil nil nil multi-char "Start in column 0, but only for single-char starters")
 (indent nil nil nil t "Full comment per line, ends not aligned")
 (aligned nil t nil t "Full comment per line, ends aligned")
 (box nil t t t "Full comment per line, ends aligned, + top and bottom")
 (extra-line t nil t t "One comment for all lines, end on a line by itself")
 (multi-line t nil nil t "One comment for all lines, end on last commented line")
 (box-multi t t t t "One comment for all lines, + top and bottom"))
```

Comment: According to the docs (`C-h v comment-styles`), your expectation is correct.  Please add the value of the variable `comment-styles` to your post.

Comment: @FranBurstall Added the value of `comment-styles` to the post. What results do you get when you perform the steps in my post with `emacs -q foo.txt`? Do you get aligned comment ends?

Comment: It looks to me that the documented (user-expected) behavior doesn't match the factual one. It's probably a good candidate for `M-x report-emacs-bug` (at least, the related docs could be added / improved), unless someone clarifies the behavior here.

Comment: @LoneLearner I get the same behaviour as you.  Looks like a bug.